# Is there a way to do this? - Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a game in batch but..

```
:start
set q1=b
set q2=c
set number=1
set q%number%=c

if q%number%==c goto ok

:nope
echo nope
pause
goto start

:ok
echo ok
pause
goto start
```

output -->

```
C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\snake>set q1=b

C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\snake>set q2=c

C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\snake>set number=1

C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\snake>set q1=c

C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\snake>if q1 == c goto ok

C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\snake>echo nope

   nope

C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\snake>pause

   Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am trying to have the var %q1%==c and not q1==c on this way.

if anyone understands me,

THNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
@echo off
set number=1
set q1=Hello
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !q%number%!
if !q%number%!==Hello echo World
```